# Can I make a customer self-service product selection tool for the web/AIR with just Flash/Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, selection, product

Can I make a customer self-service product selection tool for the web/AIR with just Flash/Actionscript 3 without having to use a separate database like SQLite?

Essentially, after selecting a general category, the client drags and drops the tag words relevant to their needs into an adjacent box and a list of products that correspond to those tags, from greatest to least, appears in the box next that.

I know that database driven apps are really on the rise but I am not clear if this situation really warrants it as I am just starting to learn (Lynda.com) and am coming from more of a content/design mentality.

Thank you and pardon my noobness.

Answer (score 1):

A pure ActionScript 3 tool would work fine, but no matter which way you slice it you will have to store somehow which products map to which tags. Whether you do this via a database, a XML file or just compile it into your application will depend many things including:

- How many products you have;
- Will the application required an Internet connection;
- How often will the database need to update.

and so on. Note also, that you will only be able to have a local SQLite database in AIR. When running in a web browser that API is not available (for Flash apps, anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I've been continually thinking about the best way to map products to tags and a database will probably cause the least pain later on even though my inclination is to make a self-contained Flash "game" out of it which would probably just be painting myself in a corner when a new line comes out. I'll have to use MySQL since that is all WP supports and forgo having a no-internet required SQLite db in a desktop AIR app.  Thanks again.

Comment: For the AIR app you can always package the preloaded SQLite database with it, so you don't need an internet connection. Since AIR has a fairly nice built in auto-update mechanism you can use that to send out updates when a new version comes out.